# How to get Wikipedia page content with internal links?

Tags: javascript, json, api, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I am trying to get text with internal links using MediaWiki API. This is what I have now:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&prop=links&action=query&prop=extracts&exlimit=max&explaintext&titles=Yahoo&redirects=
```

How can I get this text with inline links?

Answer (score 0):

To get more than one property with your query you have to separate them by pipe: `"|"`. So, your `&prop=links&prop=extracts` ([extracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Bextracts) overwrite [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Blinks)) has to be `&prop=links|extracts`, or:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Yahoo!&prop=links|extracts&pllimit=100&explaintext
```

But this is how you will get the content and the links separately. If you need to get the content with the internal links in clear **wiki markup format** you can use the same action [query](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query) with property [revisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=query%2Brevisions):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Yahoo!&rvprop=content
```

To get the same content in **HTML markup format** you can add `&rvparse` to the previous request:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Yahoo!&rvprop=content&rvparse
```

or also you can use action [parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=parse):

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=Yahoo!&prop=text
```